# lodash orderBy date in asc and desc not working

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, lodash, underscore.js

I am looking for solutions to React web application in `moment()` and `lodash` to sort date in both ascending and descending. Unfortunately, none of the solutions work.

```js
const items = {
  pageNumber: 1,
  totalPages: 1,
  content: [{
      id: 8,
      created: "2020-10-14T15:05:48.427601Z",
      actor: "Anonymous",
      rangeStart: "2020-10-14T11:54:05.610220Z",
      rangeEnd: "2020-10-14T15:05:48.461905Z",
      state: "InProgress",
      amountOrderIds: 0,
      amountOrderDetails: 0
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      created: "2020-8-11T11:54:05.610220Z",
      actor: "houman",
      rangeStart: "2020-10-11T11:54:05.610220Z",
      rangeEnd: "2020-10-14T11:54:05.610220Z",
      state: "Finished",
      amountOrderIds: 0,
      amountOrderDetails: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      created: "2020-9-10T11:53:40.262608Z",
      actor: "mo",
      rangeStart: "2020-10-10T11:53:40.262608Z",
      rangeEnd: "2020-10-11T11:53:40.262608Z",
      state: "Finished",
      amountOrderIds: 0,
      amountOrderDetails: 0
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      created: "2020-10-09T11:53:25.911596Z",
      actor: "leo",
      rangeStart: "2020-10-09T11:53:25.911596Z",
      rangeEnd: "2020-10-10T11:53:25.911596Z",
      state: "Finished",
      amountOrderIds: 0,
      amountOrderDetails: 0
    }
  ]
};

const sortByAsc = item => _.orderBy(item, () => moment(item.created), ['asc'])
const sortedAscList = (backorders) => {
  const newBackorders = _.cloneDeep(backorders)
  return _(newBackorders)
    .orderBy(sortByAsc)
    .compact()
    .value()
}
const sortByDesc = item => _.orderBy(item, () => moment(item.created), ['desc'])
const sortedDescList = (backorders) => {
  const newBackorders = _.cloneDeep(backorders)
  return _(newBackorders)
    .orderBy(sortByDesc)
    .compact()
    .value()
}

console.clear();
console.log('----------sortByAsc------------');
console.log(sortedAscList(items.content));
console.log('----------sortByDesc------------');
console.log(sortedDescList(items.content));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: don't use moment with orderBy, use Date

Comment: Or just use the string as you have it, which will sort correctly in the base sort algorithm.

Comment: `orderBy` should be called with two parameters in a chain. You're instead calling `_.orderBy` on each item but seem to want to order the whole collection. The correct syntax should be `_(newBackorders).orderBy(item => moment(item.created), ['asc'])`

Comment: @Nonik Would you mind to provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

When executing [a chain](https://lodash.com/docs/#lodash) you  are operating on *the whole dataset*. So, calling [`orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/#orderBy) doesn't need to call another `_.orderBy` in the callback. Instead, you need to call it with two parameters - the first one which is normally the collection, is implicitly the wrapped value you apply chained operations on.

```
const sortByAsc = item => _.orderBy(item, () => moment(item.created), ['asc'])
/* ... */
_(newBackorders)
    .orderBy(sortByAsc)
```

needs to become simply:

```
/* ... */
_(newBackorders)
    .orderBy(item => moment(item.created), ['asc'])
```

and a similar transformation can be done for descending.

```js
const items = {
  pageNumber: 1,
  totalPages: 1,
  content: [{
      id: 8,
      created: "2020-10-14T15:05:48.427601Z",
      actor: "Anonymous",
      rangeStart: "2020-10-14T11:54:05.610220Z",
      rangeEnd: "2020-10-14T15:05:48.461905Z",
      state: "InProgress",
      amountOrderIds: 0,
      amountOrderDetails: 0
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      created: "2020-8-11T11:54:05.610220Z",
      actor: "houman",
      rangeStart: "2020-10-11T11:54:05.610220Z",
      rangeEnd: "2020-10-14T11:54:05.610220Z",
      state: "Finished",
      amountOrderIds: 0,
      amountOrderDetails: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      created: "2020-9-10T11:53:40.262608Z",
      actor: "mo",
      rangeStart: "2020-10-10T11:53:40.262608Z",
      rangeEnd: "2020-10-11T11:53:40.262608Z",
      state: "Finished",
      amountOrderIds: 0,
      amountOrderDetails: 0
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      created: "2020-10-09T11:53:25.911596Z",
      actor: "leo",
      rangeStart: "2020-10-09T11:53:25.911596Z",
      rangeEnd: "2020-10-10T11:53:25.911596Z",
      state: "Finished",
      amountOrderIds: 0,
      amountOrderDetails: 0
    }
  ]
};

const sortedAscList = (backorders) => {
  const newBackorders = _.cloneDeep(backorders)
  return _(newBackorders)
    .orderBy(item => moment(item.created), ['asc'])
    .compact()
    .value()
}

const sortedDescList = (backorders) => {
  const newBackorders = _.cloneDeep(backorders)
  return _(newBackorders)
    .orderBy(item => moment(item.created), ['desc'])
    .compact()
    .value()
}

console.clear();
console.log('----------sortByAsc------------');
console.log(sortedAscList(items.content));
console.log('----------sortByDesc------------');
console.log(sortedDescList(items.content));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

However, that's not the only improvement here. The Moment.JS library is not needed - ISO 8601 dates *when correctly formatted* will naturally sort themselves chronologically. So, if you can fix the months to start with a zero, for example:

```
"2020-9-10T11:53:40.262608Z"
```

to

```
"2020-09-10T11:53:40.262608Z"
```

This means you can just use:

```
 _(newBackorders)
        .orderBy("created", 'asc')
```

```js
const items = {
  pageNumber: 1,
  totalPages: 1,
  content: [{
      id: 8,
      created: "2020-10-14T15:05:48.427601Z",
      actor: "Anonymous",
      rangeStart: "2020-10-14T11:54:05.610220Z",
      rangeEnd: "2020-10-14T15:05:48.461905Z",
      state: "InProgress",
      amountOrderIds: 0,
      amountOrderDetails: 0
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      created: "2020-08-11T11:54:05.610220Z",
      actor: "houman",
      rangeStart: "2020-10-11T11:54:05.610220Z",
      rangeEnd: "2020-10-14T11:54:05.610220Z",
      state: "Finished",
      amountOrderIds: 0,
      amountOrderDetails: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      created: "2020-09-10T11:53:40.262608Z",
      actor: "mo",
      rangeStart: "2020-10-10T11:53:40.262608Z",
      rangeEnd: "2020-10-11T11:53:40.262608Z",
      state: "Finished",
      amountOrderIds: 0,
      amountOrderDetails: 0
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      created: "2020-10-09T11:53:25.911596Z",
      actor: "leo",
      rangeStart: "2020-10-09T11:53:25.911596Z",
      rangeEnd: "2020-10-10T11:53:25.911596Z",
      state: "Finished",
      amountOrderIds: 0,
      amountOrderDetails: 0
    }
  ]
};

const sortedAscList = (backorders) => {
  const newBackorders = _.cloneDeep(backorders)
  return _(newBackorders)
    .orderBy("created", 'asc')
    .compact()
    .value()
}

const sortedDescList = (backorders) => {
  const newBackorders = _.cloneDeep(backorders)
  return _(newBackorders)
    .orderBy("created", 'desc')
    .compact()
    .value()
}

console.clear();
console.log('----------sortByAsc------------');
console.log(sortedAscList(items.content));
console.log('----------sortByDesc------------');
console.log(sortedDescList(items.content));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And if you want to generalise the sorting function to minimise code repetition, you can do it as a curried function:

```js
const items = { pageNumber: 1, totalPages: 1, content: [{ id: 8, created: "2020-10-14T15:05:48.427601Z", actor: "Anonymous", rangeStart: "2020-10-14T11:54:05.610220Z", rangeEnd: "2020-10-14T15:05:48.461905Z", state: "InProgress", amountOrderIds: 0, amountOrderDetails: 0 }, { id: 3, created: "2020-08-11T11:54:05.610220Z", actor: "houman", rangeStart: "2020-10-11T11:54:05.610220Z", rangeEnd: "2020-10-14T11:54:05.610220Z", state: "Finished", amountOrderIds: 0, amountOrderDetails: 0 }, { id: 2, created: "2020-09-10T11:53:40.262608Z", actor: "mo", rangeStart: "2020-10-10T11:53:40.262608Z", rangeEnd: "2020-10-11T11:53:40.262608Z", state: "Finished", amountOrderIds: 0, amountOrderDetails: 0 }, { id: 1, created: "2020-10-09T11:53:25.911596Z", actor: "leo", rangeStart: "2020-10-09T11:53:25.911596Z", rangeEnd: "2020-10-10T11:53:25.911596Z", state: "Finished", amountOrderIds: 0, amountOrderDetails: 0 } ] };

const sortList = order => (backorders) => {
  const newBackorders = _.cloneDeep(backorders)
  return _(newBackorders)
    .orderBy("created", order)
    .compact()
    .value()
}

const sortedAscList = sortList('asc');

const sortedDescList = sortList('desc');

console.clear();
console.log('----------sortByAsc------------');
console.log(sortedAscList(items.content));
console.log('----------sortByDesc------------');
console.log(sortedDescList(items.content));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, using [`_.partial`](https://lodash.com/docs/#partial):

```js
const items = { pageNumber: 1, totalPages: 1, content: [{ id: 8, created: "2020-10-14T15:05:48.427601Z", actor: "Anonymous", rangeStart: "2020-10-14T11:54:05.610220Z", rangeEnd: "2020-10-14T15:05:48.461905Z", state: "InProgress", amountOrderIds: 0, amountOrderDetails: 0 }, { id: 3, created: "2020-08-11T11:54:05.610220Z", actor: "houman", rangeStart: "2020-10-11T11:54:05.610220Z", rangeEnd: "2020-10-14T11:54:05.610220Z", state: "Finished", amountOrderIds: 0, amountOrderDetails: 0 }, { id: 2, created: "2020-09-10T11:53:40.262608Z", actor: "mo", rangeStart: "2020-10-10T11:53:40.262608Z", rangeEnd: "2020-10-11T11:53:40.262608Z", state: "Finished", amountOrderIds: 0, amountOrderDetails: 0 }, { id: 1, created: "2020-10-09T11:53:25.911596Z", actor: "leo", rangeStart: "2020-10-09T11:53:25.911596Z", rangeEnd: "2020-10-10T11:53:25.911596Z", state: "Finished", amountOrderIds: 0, amountOrderDetails: 0 } ] };

const sortList = (order, backorders) => {
  const newBackorders = _.cloneDeep(backorders)
  return _(newBackorders)
    .orderBy("created", order)
    .compact()
    .value()
}

const sortedAscList = _.partial(sortList, 'asc');

const sortedDescList = _.partial(sortList, 'desc');

console.clear();
console.log('----------sortByAsc------------');
console.log(sortedAscList(items.content));
console.log('----------sortByDesc------------');
console.log(sortedDescList(items.content));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```